# Populating a fragment list from a database

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, android-fragments, actionbarsherlock

I have a question. :)
In an app that I am working on, in one part I have two tabs, both run by their respective fragment and a listview in each one.
Now, I need to populate those lists with the data I am reading in an SQLite database. I created almost all necessary classes for the DB part, but I am stuck on a part where I need to get this data

```
 public List<String> getAllRockBands() {
     List<String> bandList = new ArrayList<String>();

     String selection = BAND_GENRE + "=1";
     String orderBy = BAND_NAME+" ASC";

     SQLiteDatabase db = sqLiteHelper.getReadableDatabase();
     Cursor cursor = db.query(BANDDATABASE_TABLE,new String[]{BAND_NAME}, selection,  null, null, null, orderBy);

     int index = cursor.getColumnIndex(BAND_NAME);

     if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
         do {
          String bandName = cursor.getString(index);
              bandList.add(bandName);
         } while (cursor.moveToNext());
     }

     return bandList;
 }
```

from my sqlhelper class to my listfragment extended class. The code for it is currently:

```
public class RockAllFragment extends SherlockListFragment {

private String[] bandList;

 @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

     return inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_list, null);
 }

  @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setRetainInstance(true);
 }

 @Override
 public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getSherlockActivity(),   android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, android.R.id.text1, bandList));
 }
}
```

Going with `private BandDatabaseAdapter mySQLiteAdapter;` and using the method through that works only for Activity extended classes and not ListFragment? What would be the best way to acomplish what I want to do? (P.S. I am pretty new to programming for Android, sorry if I made some trivial mistakes :)

Thanks,
Aleksa

Comment: A `CursorAdapter` would fit better for your scenario. A _custom adapter_ would be even better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end I found out it was a clumsy starter mistake, just going with `mySQLiteAdapter = new DatabaseAdapter(getSherlockActivity());` at `onViewCreated` and using an array adapter worked just fine.

Answer (score 1):

A [CursorAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html) is what you want.

You would simply hook it to the [Cursor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html) returned from your query. Just extend CursorAdapter and implement the `newView()` and `bindView()` methods.

Comment: Where to implement those methods and which class to extend with CursorAdapter (I am already exdending ListFragment, that's why I ask)?